# How to install mod_wsgi for apache 2.4 and python 3.4 on windows?

Tags: django, python-3.x, xampp, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I had apache 2.4 already installed with xampp.I tried adding mod_wsgi using the steps mentioned [here](https://www.devbattles.com/en/sand/post-304-using+Apache+and+Python+WSGI+on+Windows)

But when I add the line

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi-py34-vc10.so
```

Apache does not start.

Answer (score 12):

It is better to build mod_wsgi yourself from code rather than use an arbitrary binary off the net. The steps are as follows.

- Ensure you have a decent Apache installation which includes header files, e.g. [Apache 2.4.37 Win64 from Apache Lounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/) . Preferably installed at location of `C:/Apache24`.
- Ensure your Python installation is set up so that you can `pip` install modules. This must include having the correct Microsoft C compiler needed by that Python version.
- Run `pip install mod_wsgi`. If your Apache installation is not at `C:/Apache24`, then first set the environment variable `MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR` to its location. Ensure you specify path as `C:/Apache24` form and not with back slashes, that is, not as `C:\Apache24`. This is only needed when doing the install, not later.
- Run `mod_wsgi-express module-config`.
- Copy the output from runing `mod_wsgi-express module-config` into your Apache configuration file.
- Add configuration for a WSGI application to the Apache configuration.
- Restart Apache and see if it works.

Note that you are better off starting with a WSGI hello world rather than some huge Django application when initially testing.

Comment: Thanks.I started learning Django instead.Using their server for now

Comment: When I run `pip install mod_wsgi` it fails with `c:\apache24\include\apr_network_io.h(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'apr_perms_set.h': No such file or directory'.` This is with httpd 2.4.27. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: The above attempt was with source I downloaded from `http://mirrors.gigenet.com/apache/httpd/httpd-2.4.27.tar.gz`. I just tried building with source cloned from github and that failed with `c:\apache24\include\ap_hooks.h(39) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'apr.h': No such file or directory`

Comment: I thought this was the same question, and I tried your solution and I had issues. That is why I asked in the comments. I will create a new question.

Comment: "first set the environment variable MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR to its location". How is this done?

Comment: That depends on what shell you are using on Windows. Have you looked up "How to set environment variable from shell in Windows"?

Comment: in windows cmd setting the environment variable is done via `set MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=c:/path/to/apache`
Note that it will be unset as soon as you close the cms

Comment: You might have to install visual studio build tools for this to work. These can be found on the https://visualstudio,microsoft.com/downloads/ under tools.
In the following menue you have to choose cpp build tools and of those you only need the windows 10 sdk (around 4.5 GB)

Comment: I've posted a question about the missing include files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54268396/cannot-open-include-file-apr-perms-set-h-when-doing-pip-install-mod-wsgi

Comment: Where to add the return of the mod_wsgi-express module-config cmd in the httpd.conf? Do I open a directory for this, or do I have to add it to some existing one in the file? The document doesnt clarify it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the release of Apache Lounge , if you still find  `c:\apache24\include\apr_network_io.h(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'apr_perms_set.h': No such file or directory'.` .
This is best fit to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

```
This topic is useful for Windows 10, xampp webserver as well.
I was struggling to find precompiled mod_wsgi.so for 
Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) 
Python/2.7.13 
This [link][1] is useful to find the appropriate version of mod_wsgi.
IF you are lucky, you can find the precompiled version [here][2]
There is a step by step guidance available [here][3]


  [1]: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst
  [2]: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi
  [3]: https://everything2.com/title/Installing+Python+on+XAMPP
```

Comment: The recommended method is to build it yourself using ``pip install mod_wsgi`` as explain in another answer. Grabbing arbitrary binaries is not guaranteed to work. You should build it for your specific Apache installation.

Comment: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ saved me a lot of time getting the VC compiler toolchain on my machine. Basically `pip install <.whl file>`, then continue following the instructions here: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

Answer (score 1):

@LarryMartell
I met the same issue on windows and fixed it.
You can try to copy file `apr_perms_set.h` from `apr` repository (https://github.com/traviscross/apr) to Apache2.4's include folder.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. Copying APR header files from a separate repo is also not guaranteed to work anyway if the issue was they were missing. Use a Apache distro which ships header files instead. If you aren't use the exact same header files as the Apache was compiled with, you can encounter problems.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a 64 bit operating system and have 64 bit python installed.

installing apache distribution for 64 bit OS from apachelounge https://www.apachelounge.com/download/  resolved the problem for me.

Comment: Yes, this is the only solution I've found so far. A question stays how to fix it for ApacheHaus: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54268396/cannot-open-include-file-apr-perms-set-h-when-doing-pip-install-mod-wsgi