# pip install mod_wsgi, How to Set MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR environment?

Tags: python, apache, pip, mod-wsgi

I am trying to install mod_wsgi in Windows 10.

The command `pip install mod_wsgi` is giving me error,

`RuntimeError: No Apache installation can be found. Set the MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR environment to its location.`

My Apache dir is `F:\Apache24\`.

My question is, how to setup MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR environment ?

Thanks,
Sambhav

Comment: Where is you wsgi file?

Comment: pip install mod_wsgi doesn't require prior download of the file. It does it for you.

As @Alisdair suggested, I ran the command `set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=F:\Apache24"` and then executed `pip install mod_wsgi` and it crossed that point but now it is giving me `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`. Any idea about error ?

Thanks,
Sambhav

Comment: Don't use backslashes in path when setting that environment variable. Have had some reports that backslash doesn't work. use ``set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=F:/Apache24"`` if using CMD shell. It is probably related to how Windows shell handles backslash escapes. Use forward slash and avoid any issues.

Comment: BTW, steps for what you need to do after installation are explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42307082/128141

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Referring to the docs at http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/release-notes/version-4.5.12.html should help you.

**In Short:**

By default the installation looks for Apache in `C:\Apache24`, `C:\Apache22` and `C:\Apache2`, as your installation is none of these you need to set the environment variable `MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR` to the path you have installed it to.

On your system you would do this by running this in your command prompt:

`set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=F:\Apache24"`

Which sets the variable, and then you can run the pip command (in the same command prompt):

`pip install mod_wsgi`

---

To read more about the `set` command run `set /?` in command prompt.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Need further help, After executing the above commands I am getting `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`. Could you please help in this as well ?

Thank you,
Sambhav

Comment: vcvarsall.bat is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler, mod_wsgi must be trying to compile some C code on installation, if this is Python 2.7 just use the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Or for Python 3.5 you'll need to install Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Right, I am using Python 3.5. now to resolve this issue I am installing VC++ 2008 express.

Thanks again,
Sambhav

Comment: If you are using Python 3.5, you should not be using VC++ 2008. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers You want 'Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 standalone'.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton for pointing in the correct direction, I will try the same.

Regards, Sambhav

Comment: Just an update, Finally was able to install it. The last issue came about the unresolved external libraries and symbols which was because I was accidently running 32-bit Python instead of 64 bit. So installed 64 bit and after that installation went successfully. Thank you for help Alisdair Robertson and @GrahamDumpleton for the help.

Regards,
Sambhav

Comment: I have installed the apache through wamp installation. Can someone direct me where's is the Apache installation directory?

I have tried 
**wamp/bin/apache**
**wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23**
**wamp/www**

None worked.

Comment: You may run into problems later if you used `set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=F:\Apache24"`. To be safe, use a forward slash: `set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=F:/Apache24"`

Answer (score 2):

If **pip install mod_wsgi** cannot find the apache root dir and asked to set (**MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR**) env variable.

```
set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=F:\Apache24"
```

does not work in pycharm terminal (powershell), use below instead (verify path)

```
$env:MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR = "C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.51"
```