# problems with pip install mod-wsgi

Tags: python, django, cmd, pip, mod-wsgi

I'm new IT and programming; I been struggling to install mod_wsgi with pip

Example in cmd:

```
pip install mod_wsgi
```

I been trying to lunch my django project on my own pc acting as a server

I'm using **Apcache 24** and my **PC is windows 10, 64bits**

My **python is 3.7.1** and **Django is 2.1.3**

**Solution I had try:**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42323871/10865416

error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I had check and and intsall the C++ 14 here the link where I download:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=48145

2. download and install manually
   https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/148#issuecomment-374853521

error:

```
C:\Users\user>pip install C:/mod_wsgi-4.5.24+ap24vc14-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.rar
Invalid requirement: 'C:/mod_wsgi-4.5.24+ap24vc14-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.rar'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 93, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1654, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1644, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1402, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3417, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1406, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3205, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\constructors.py", line 253, in install_req_from_line
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8], e.msg
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Parse error at "':/mod_ws'": Expected stringEnd
```

3. https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

error:

```
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f9igth3o\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kmcbksbk\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f9igth3o\mod-wsgi\
```

and yes hd VC10 install to had this error, here the link https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

In advance thank you for your help, apprentice it

Comment: Number 2 is telling you that the file does not exist. Did you download it and place it in that location?

Comment: Could be wrong, but that filename on Number 2, looks like it has a typo on it, can You double check that?

Comment: Who am I to give advice, but please use Unix systems. It will save a lot of time.

Comment: The download page above points not to Visual C++ but only to Redistributable packages. They install run-time libraries that are used to run applications written with VC. But you need Visual C++ compiler! Install [Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: so the third method is also not the builds tools? here the link:https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Some of the pip packages are downloaded as source code, then compiled on the user pc and installed, to compile certain packages different c++ libraries and header files are required, which  comes with `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0` package. You have installed `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015`, which installs `run-time components` that are required to run C++ applications built using Visual Studio 2015, not `compiler libraries` which are required to compile from source. You have to install Visual Studio C++ packages, From this link [Visual studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15#).
2. Your python version is `3.7.1`, you are trying to install `mod_wsgi-4.5.24+ap24vc14-cp35-cp35m-wind_amd64.whl` which is compiled to work for python version `3.5`, on Windows `x86_64` arch, not compatible for your system.
3. Again, required C++ libraries not found in your system.

Comment: Hi arryph I follow the link and install the visual studio, but  again, it can't find the required C++ libraries, now I'm lost on where to even find the installation software for VC

Answer (score 2):

Hi I've been struggling with the same issue lately, 
the way I found to overcome it was to download Microsoft Visual studio, and then start a new C++ project.
MVS will download the required components to compile mod_wsgi and everything should be fine after that

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean but, I tried I open MVS and open new C++ project, then I went back cmd to and pip install mod_wsgi, But I still had same error in 3

Answer (score 1):

Now I really feel very silly;

I figure out why the system install mod_wsgi 64bits because my python is in 32 bits.

but thank you so much on helping me, lead me to solve my problem both ubisun and arryph