# django, apache, mod_wsgi on Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to get a django app running on Windows Server 2016 using apache and mod_wsgi. I have tried many, many different things based on what I have read at these (and other) links:

[How to install mod_wsgi for apache 2.4 and python 3.4 on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298503/how-to-install-mod-wsgi-for-apache-2-4-and-python-3-4-on-windows)

https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

Currently I have apache installed from https://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC10/binaries/httpd-2.4.23-win32.zip and `pip install mod_wsgi` runs without errors, but when I run `mod_wsgi-express module-config`I get:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/python27/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgiNone"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/python27"
```

What is that None at the end of the path?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The ``None`` is caused by a bug in the script affecting some people with Python 2.7 which I can't seem to get anyone to help me to work out what the issue is. The simple fix is not to use Python 2.7. You should be using latest Python 3 anyway unless you gave a very good reason not to. If you really want to see a fix, please use the mod_wsgi mailing list to raise the problem and can then have a proper discussion there about it. SO is no good for doing debugging.

Comment: I have an existing django app that runs in linux. I have successfully deployed it with Docker, vagrant/VirtualBox, VMware, kvm, and on bare metal. But now I have prospective client that refuses to run linux, even in a VM. So I am tying to get my app running on Windows Server 2016, piece by painful piece.I really don't want to start porting it to 3.5 right now. I will post on the mailing list.