# `Cannot open include file: 'apr_perms_set.h'` when doing `pip install mod_wsgi`

Tags: python, c, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to roll out a production Django environment on Windows 10 with Apache 2.4.37 x64 [OpenSSL 1.1.1 VC14 from ApacheHaus](https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx). However, when following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42307082/1915854), I'm getting the following error:

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -ID:/Servers/Web/Apache/Apache24/include -Ic:\programs\python37\include -Ic:\programs\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/server\mod_wsgi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.obj
  mod_wsgi.c
  d:\servers\web\apache\apache24\include\apr_network_io.h(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'apr_perms_set.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mod-wsgi
```

I see the following options to C/C++ compiler: `-ID:/Servers/Web/Apache/Apache24/include -Ic:\programs\python37\include` . So it seems include file `apr_perms_set.h` is missing from Apache or Python.

How to fix this error with the correct versions of the include files? I'm afraid it's wrong to just take the latest version from a repository because it may not match what's Apache or mod-wsgi expect.

Comment: `apr` stands for Apache Portable (C) Runtime, so that's the side where it should exist, not Python. See if you can find it on disk in the A includes at all...

Answer (score 8):

I had similar error on Windows Server 2016, when trying to use Apache 2.4 64bit  with Python 2.7. Apparently apr header files were missing. I was able to solve it by:

- making sure I have both Apache and Python 64bit (guess it'll be valid
  for 32bit as well) installing [VC++
  Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=52685) - of course 64bit in my case
- downloading Apache Runtime (apr) headers from [APR project website](https://apr.apache.org)
- copying missing header file from downloaded sources into Apache's **include** folder
- installing **mod_wsgi** with `pip install mod_wsgi` (inside my virtual environment).

Comment: I have copied the missing file (apr_perms_set.h) from downloaded Apache Runtime files to `c:/apache24/include` folder and then executed `py setup.py install` from mod_wsgi folder

Comment: Ticket opened here https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64304

Answer (score 2):

The distribution from The Apache Haus does not include the aforementioned header file for some strange reason. Try using the distribution from [Apache Lounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/), it should contain all header files needed to compile mod_wsgi (tested with httpd-2.4.41-win32-VS16.zip).

Comment: This worked for me. They should include those headers. The whole point of distributing a binary is convenience!

Answer (score 1):

You can download the missing file from Github and copy it in the directory

```
C:/Apache24/include
```

Comment: which github? This isn't that helpful!