# Problems with mod-wsgi Windows

Tags: python, django, apache, pip, mod-wsgi

I'm new IT and programming; I been struggling to install mod_wsgi with pip

Example in cmd:

`pip install mod_wsgi`

I'm using **Apcache 24** and my **PC is windows 10, 64bits**

My **python is 3.7.9** and **Django is 3.2.16**

Error :

```
Building wheels for collected packages: mod-wsgi
  Building wheel for mod-wsgi (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi
      copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
      copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
      copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
      copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management
      copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
      copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
      copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\docs
      copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\docs
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
      copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
      copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
      running build_ext
      building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
      error: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mod-wsgi
  Running setup.py clean for mod-wsgi
Failed to build mod-wsgi
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi
  Running setup.py install for mod-wsgi ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

Solution that I already tried:

[How to fix ERROR while installing WSGI for PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61736551/how-to-fix-error-while-installing-wsgi-for-python)