# How To solve "Error C1083" when Install mod_wsgi in windows? file 'ws2tcpip.h'

Tags: python, c++, windows, mod-wsgi

I try to install mod_wsgi for windows I install the diferentes requirements about C and C++, and this other stuff, about Visual Studio etc..

But I got this error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 
'Z:\PROGRAMACION\6_BACKEND\envpy\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-req-build-jdxut7hw\\setup.py'"'"';
 __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-req-build-jdxut7hw\\setup.py'"'"';
f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-wheel-7xzm29_v'
       cwd: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-req-build-jdxut7hw\
  Complete output (31 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi
  copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
  copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
  copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
  copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management
  copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
  copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
  copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\docs
  copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\docs
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
  copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
  copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
  running build_ext
  building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src\server
  
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\Apache24/include -IZ:\PROGRAMACION\6_BACKEND\envpy\include -Ic:\users\andres\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\andres\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include" "
-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcsrc/server\mod_wsgi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.obj
  mod_wsgi.c
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-req-build-jdxut7hw\src\server\wsgi_apache.h(39): 
fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'ws2tcpip.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mod-wsgi
  Running setup.py clean for mod-wsgi
Failed to build mod-wsgi
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi
    Running setup.py install for mod-wsgi ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'Z:\PROGRAMACION\6_BACKEND\envpy\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-req-build-jdxut7hw\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-req-build-jdxut7hw\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-record-10zpln53\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'Z:\PROGRAMACION\6_BACKEND\envpy\include\site\python3.8\mod-wsgi'
         cwd: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-req-build-jdxut7hw\
    Complete output (31 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi
    copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management
    copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\docs
    copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\docs
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
    running build_ext
    building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src\server
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\Apache24/include -IZ:\PROGRAMACION\6_BACKEND\envpy\include -Ic:\users\andres\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\andres\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcsrc/server\mod_wsgi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.obj
    mod_wsgi.c
    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-req-build-jdxut7hw\src\server\wsgi_apache.h(39): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'ws2tcpip.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'Z:\PROGRAMACION\6_BACKEND\envpy\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-req-build-jdxut7hw\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-req-build-jdxut7hw\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-record-10zpln53\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'Z:\PROGRAMACION\6_BACKEND\envpy\include\site\python3.8\mod-wsgi' Check the logs for full command output.
```

My Specific error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open file include: 'ws2tcpip.h': No such file or directory
```

`'ws2tcpip.h'` my file is diferent

I See:

[Testing installation of mod_wsgi on Windows.](https://groups.google.com/g/modwsgi/c/OTb_gN8kX7w/m/xROh3RP8BAAJ) for the Graham Dumpleton the creator of this module.

I search here And I got Similar errors but diferentes library
for example Error atemp install connector of MySQL: [`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51294860/16311518)

But In diferents answere in stack overflow sugest that you can donwload a file with extension `whl` then I went at this page [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi) and I dowload `mod_wsgi-4.9.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

I then I put this **strange** file in folder of virtual enviroment `site-packages`
Then I try with the virtual env activate:

`pip install "$ .\envpy\Lib\site-packages\mod_wsgi-4.9.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl"`

In my case the full path is:
`pip install "Z:\PROGRAMACION\6_BACKEND\envpy\Lib\site-packages\mod_wsgi-4.9.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl"`

And the installation was well. The output in the `cmd` was the installation was well and If I entry in

`cd Z:\PROGRAMACION\6_BACKEND\envpy\Lib\site-packages\`

I can see the folder `\mod_wsgi\`

but I *am no sure* if this installation will be funtional. I don't know if the installation with pip, instal other stuff, other files for example in apache folder like `apache\include` or in `apache\modules`

Y see this blog too [Error C1083 al compilar extensiones con Visual Studio 2015](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/error-c1083-vs2015/)

But I don't know in which part of the script `setup.py` I needed to changue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`Cannot open include file: 'apr\_perms\_set.h'\` when doing \`pip install mod\_wsgi\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54268396/cannot-open-include-file-apr-perms-set-h-when-doing-pip-install-mod-wsgi)

Comment: No it is not the same file, it is the same error, my preocupation it is about with the conventional installation install diferents stuff in the rest of muy folders, like `$ path\to\apache` etc... only this... I run the coman `mod_wsgi-express module-config` in the virtual env, and the output was: 
`LoadFile "c:/users/andres/appdata/local/programs/python/python38/python38.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "z:/programacion/6_backend/envpy/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp38-win_amd64.pyd"

WSGIPythonHome "z:/programacion/6_backend/envpy"`